# How Is Serializable ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, serialization, thread-local

I'm trying to serialize a neural network,but I'm faced with the fact that I don't know how to do it. My code.

```
public class Layer implements Serializable {
private final int size;
private ThreadLocal<Vec> out = new ThreadLocal<>();
private Activation activation;
private Optimizer optimizer;
private Matrix weights;
private Vec bias;
private double l2 = 0;

private Layer precedingLayer;
```

But when serializing, I get the following exception - Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.ThreadLocal
How can I serialize my class?

Comment: Shouldn't `out` be a `static` field? [Per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html?is-external=true): `ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).`

Comment: If I make this field static, it will definitely not be serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a field in your Layer class does not implement Serializable, java does not know how to serialize an instance of Layer.

Specifically, as the exception message indicates, `ThreadLocal<Vec> out` is one such field that cannot be serialized, and if look at the class you'll see that it does not implement the Serializable interface.

ThreadLocal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Serializable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

You could probably make a class like this that will compile:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableThreadLocal<T> extends ThreadLocal<T> implements Serializable {

}
```

Then instantiate an instance of `SerializableThreadLocal` when you start off, like this:

```
private ThreadLocal<Vec> out = new SerializableThreadLocal<Vec>();
```